# No Deployments Created when Creating a Spring Boot App

Tags: azure-spring-boot

I have deployed a spring app called shape-shop-app :

[image]

It says the application failed to start and I should check the logs.

This is what it looks like in Azure :

[image]

This is where I am confused.

Where are the logs?

If I go to the console for shape-shop-app then it is empty.

[image]

If I go to the "Azure Spring Apps" Logs tab then I am bombarded with thousands of queries I can choose from. I really just want to find out what error caused my spring app to go down but I am lost among all these specific log queries. The most generic queries yield no results.

How can I diagnose why my spring app failed to start in azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Application failed to start.

Generally, this error occurs when the application is not deployed properly (or) If any file/configuration is missing. Re-deploy your application to fix the issue.

> If I go to the console for shape-shop-app then it is empty.

Select your *App instance* from the drop down in the *Console* and click on *Connect*.

[image]

***To check the logs use the query:***

> az spring app logs --resource-group <Resource_group_name> --service <Service_instance_name> --name <App_name> --follow

[image]

Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/quickstart-logs-metrics-tracing?tabs=Azure-CLI&pivots=programming-language-java) for Monitoring Azure Spring Apps with logs, metrics, and tracing.

- You can also enable Remote debugging. This helps to attach a debugger to the application and figure out the issue.

[image]

---

**Try to deploy your application as shown below:**

Go to the root folder of your spring-boot application and run the below commands:

```
mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-apps-maven-plugin:1.17.0:config
```

[image]
[image]

- `mvn clean install`

[image]

**Deploy:**

- `mvn azure-spring-apps:deploy`

[image]
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Assign Endpoint:**

[image]

It generates the URL as shown below:

[image]

***Response:***

[image]

Comment: thankyou kindly for your answer.  I tried to look at the logs but it comes back as NOT FOUND : C:\dev\petsitter-backend>az spring app logs --resource-group shapeShopResourceGroup --service shapeshop2 --name petsitter-backend-app --follow
Operation returned an invalid status 'Not Found'

Comment: @OliverWatkins, Check if Service Instance name `service shapeshop2` and application name `--name petsitter-backend-app` is valid and available.

Comment: having no luck with the az console. It is really terrible. I am going to try your suggestion with debugging from IntelliJ :)

Comment: No luck with remote debugging either. I have opened a seperate ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76663790/cannot-find-remote-debug-setting-for-a-spring-boot-app-in-azure

Comment: Can you try to deploy your application with the steps I gave in the answer?

Comment: sorry...............done