# Cannot find "remote debug" Setting for a Spring Boot App in Azure

Tags: azure-spring-cloud, azure-spring-boot

According to the documentation. I can setup remote debugging for my Spring Boot App by navigating to the list item shown in the screenshot below :

[image]

If I navigate to my "App" then I cannot find this item in the settings list.

[image]

[ On a side note why are the icons different? Is a running app a green arrow, or a grid of blue squares? ]

Answer (score 0):

[Debug your apps remotely in Azure Spring Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/how-to-remote-debugging-app-instance?tabs=portal%2Cazure-portal%2CIntellij-extension) currently only applies to Azure Spring Apps of  Basic/Standard/Enterprise plans.

It appears that you are currently utilizing the new Standard Consumption and Dedicated plan, which does not support the Remote Debug feature at the moment. However, the Azure product group is planing on implementing support for this feature in the new plan.